# Arduino filling serial buffer with nulls

Tags: string, arduino, null, serial-port, processing

I just wrote some code that just sends a String from Arduino to Processing. Processing prints the string in ASCII.
After uploading the sketch to the Arduino and starting Processing for the first time, The serial Buffer is initially filled with **nulls**. Why is this happening?
And this **mostly** happens after uploading and starting Processing **for the first time**. When I start Processing for the second time, the buffer is initially free as it should be. I am using a genuine Arduino Uno. I also tested on another Arduino and another Laptop but still the same problem. So it should not be a hardware problem.

**Arduino Code**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
//delay(1000)
 Serial.println("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
 delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
}
```

**Processing Code**

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  myPort= new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (myPort.available()>0) {
    int c =myPort.read();
    print(c,",");
  }
}
```

**Output on Processing**

```
0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,116 ,104 ,101 ,32 ,113 ,117 ,105 ,99 ,107 ,32 ,98 ,114 ,111 ,119 ,110 ,32 ,102 ,111 ,120 ,32 ,106 ,117 ,109 ,112 ,115 ,32 ,111 ,118 ,101 ,114 ,32 ,116 ,104 ,101 ,32 ,108 ,97 ,122 ,121 ,32 ,100 ,111 ,103
```

Comment: try flushing the port just after opening it.

Comment: I did that too with myPort.clear() in the setup function. But nothing changed

Comment: Try calling [`myPort.bufferUntil('\n');`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html) in `setup()`, adding [`serialEvent()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_serialEvent_.html) where you call [`myPort.readString()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readString_.html). Hopefully this saves you a few headaches reading the text byte by byte (including the empty buffer). (if you plan to use `readString()` it's good idea to check the result isn't `null` and trimming whitespace after (by calling `trim()` on the String)).

Comment: same question on Arduino SE with more details and comments https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90699/arduino-filling-serial-buffer-with-nulls

Comment: `Serial.begin()` took about 100mS to be ready, so try to comment in delay before `Serial.println()` and the delay after the `Serial.println()`. Or alternatively, change the `if (Serial.available() > 0)` to `while (!Serial.availabel()) { // wait }` on the receiving end.